# How do I restore the USB drive auto-mounting in xenial?

Tags: 16.04, automount

External USB drives stopped AUTO-MOUNTING after upgrade to XENIAL. How do I restore that feature? My default session is KODI.

Comment: Check in fstab whether your usb drive has been added.

Comment: @vembutech Nope it has not.

Answer (score 0):

In Unity sessión
Use gnome-disk-utility (DISK), select your drive on the left side and click on the gear icon. Select additional mounting options

Comment: I don't use unity I have Ubuntu MATE, I prefer a command line solution.